# Draggable list into html5 table has bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

There are two lists of items need to be mapped into a table. I've create the table and draggable list item followed by reference-style link to [Accessing table cell data within list items with Javascript](http://www.authorcode.com/drag-li-element-and-drop-to-td-of-the-html-table-using-jquery-ui/).

### The current situation

I have two lists, and need to be filled into two columns(with different ids); ideally, the the credit card list item can only be put into credit card column, vice versa for api list and api field.

### The current issue

1. When I dragged items from api list to api field, it displayed double text.
2. Two list items can drag into different fields. How can I make the list items limited into matched table column?

Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gctemr61/) along with some sample code:

```
$("#ccField li").draggable({
  appendTo: "body",
  helper: "clone",
  cursor: "move",
  revert: "invalid"
});

$("#apiField li").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
    revert: "invalid"
});

ccDroppable($("#creditCardApiTable table td"));

apiDroppable($("#creditCardApiTable table td"));

function ccDroppable($elements) {
    $elements.droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-drop-hover",
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",

        over: function (event, ui) {
            var $this = $(this);
        },
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $("<span></span>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
            $("#ccList").find(":contains('" + ui.draggable.text() + "')")[0].remove();
        }
    });
}

function apiDroppable($elements) {
    $elements.droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-drop-hover",
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",

        over: function (event, ui) {
            var $this = $(this);
        },
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $("<span></span>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
            $("#apiList").find(":contains('" + ui.draggable.text() + "')")[0].remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/ryaL3xpk/3/

```
$("#ccField li").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
    revert: "invalid"
});

$("#apiField li").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
    revert: "invalid"
});

function droppableField($element, $accept) {
    $element.droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-drop-hover",
        accept: $accept,
        over: function (event, ui) {
            var $this = $(this);
        },
        greedy:true,
        tolerance:'touch',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
        }
    });
}

droppableField($('#creditCardApiTable table td .ccDropField'), '#ccField li');
droppableField($('#creditCardApiTable table td .apiDropField'), '#apiList li');
```

So basically, you allow each `span` to be droppable, and each accepts different draggable field.